# Custom header is not send using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I have this code that send request to Wikipedia API (as documented [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)) but when I look at network tab in Chromium the header `Api-User-Agent` is not send, why?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
    data: {
        action: 'query',
        prop:'revisions',
        rvprop: 'content',
        format:'json',
        titles: 'Hacker_culture'
    },
    headers: {
        'Api-User-Agent': 'Example Agent'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send headers in jsonp requests the same way you can't use POST for them. They aren't XmlHttpRequest's they are script requests.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP